# The constructor Session(String,int) is not visible

Tags: java

I have a jar that contains a class file Session.class. I did a import of all the jar and this class that I want to use. In my code as below:

```
public AgentInfo[] getInfo(){
    try {   
        session = new Session(host,port);
    }
}
```

Here I am getting error

```
 The constructor Session(String,int) is not visible
```

Answer (score 3):

That suggests that the `Session(String, int)` constructor isn't public. For example, it might be declared like this:

```
Session(String host, int port)
```

instead of

```
public Session(String host, int port)
```

(It might be protected or even final, of course.)

If you can change `Session` *and want to*, you can make the constructor public. If you can't change it (e.g. it's a 3rd party class) you should look at what constructors *are* available, and also check for static methods returning `Session`, factory classes (e.g. `SessionFactory`) etc. Generally the documentation is a good start to find out how you're meant to get hold of an instance of a class :)

Comment: @Mandakini: Okay, so the last paragraph applies - you won't be able to call that constructor, so work out how else you're meant to do it.

Comment: public class Session
{  String _host;
  int _port;
  Socket _socket;
  boolean _use_unix_domain;
  String _udSocketFile;
  UnixDomainSocketClient _udSocket;
    protected Session(String paramString, int paramInt)
    throws ErrorInfo
  {
    this._host = paramString;
    this._inStream = null;

    this._udSocket = null;
    this._udSocketFile = null;
    try
    {
      this._user = System.getProperty("user.name");
      this._privdir = SearchPath.privpath("");
    }
    catch (AccessControlException localAccessControlException)
    {
      this._user = "";
      this._privdir = "";
    }
  }

Comment: @Manakini: Well, that suggests that only subclasses can construct an instance. It would really help if instead of posting the source code as a comment, you could just let us know which library this is...

Comment: It is a third party jar that i have added to my library.I am importing it. What is the way i can use the protected class ????

Comment: @Mandakini: You'd have to create a subclass - but chances are that's not the right way to go. Again, is this a public third party library that we could look at? There should be some documentation explaining how you're meant to use it.

Comment: Its in mimic.jar ...Session.class...Probably u can get it in http://www.gambitcomm.com

Comment: @Manakini: If it's a commercial library, surely there's documentation. Aren't there any tutorials showing you this sort of thing? Or at least Javadoc? You shouldn't need to *guess* what to do.

Comment: I did not get any...I will check with them probably..I can see the .class files...using decompiler i could see the .java file...But i donot see any method that i can use...

Comment: @Mandakini: If you don't have any documentation, you've got bigger problems than this. Trying to use an API with no clear guidance is going to cause you a lot of pain.

Answer (score 1):

Very likely the constructor is private or protected or package access only. Are you sure you need to use that class? There might be derived classes that are better suited (or the class is supposed to be extended)

Comment: I can not change the Session defination which is 3rd party .class file

Comment: That is why I asked, why you need it? Why don't you check for derived classes, or perhaps that thing is only used internaly and you don't need it at all!!

Answer (score 0):

constructor probably is not public, if you have the source make it public or use some other constructor. oor if there is no visible constructor there is some factory for creating instances

Comment: I can not change the Session defination which is 3rd party .class file

Answer (score 0):

Since you have access to the class file inside the zip file, view it in your IDE or run `javap` on it.

Chances are there is a *static factory method* returning session objects somewhere in that class or in a related class.  This is common in cases where there are many types of sessions available.

Comment: I can not change the Session defination which is 3rd party .class file

Comment: Right, and you're not _supposed_ to change the definition!  I suggested to look inside the class file, or the class files of whichever library this came from (or even the documentation for the library) to find out how sessions are supposed to be created.  I'm sure somewhere something says you need to call `SessionFactory.getSession()` or something like that.